# Running alternative version of Python on RedHat 6 produces "wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64"

Tags: python, pandas, redhat, elf

I inherited some python code that I need to modify. I installed python 2.7.10 on my RedHat 6 machine and ran the original code which produced results different from those that were generated last time it was run using an older version of python. I was given a path to an old python installation and tried to run the code using it. Got errors. Here's what I've done so far:

This is the path to the old python install (2.7.8):

```
PROMPT ] alias oldpy='/oldinstall/Python/bin/python'
```

Tried running the code and got the first error:

```
PROMPT ] oldpy ./myScript.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myScript.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/oldinstall/Python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from pandas.io.api import *
  File "/oldinstall/Python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/api.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas.io.packers import read_msgpack, to_msgpack
  File "/oldinstall/Python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/packers.py", line 63, in <module>
    from pandas.msgpack import Unpacker as _Unpacker, Packer as _Packer
ImportError: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Searched for `libstdc++.so.6` and found it in `/usr/lib64`:

```
PROMPT ] ll /usr/lib64/libstdc*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     18 Jul 20  2012 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.5 -> libstdc++.so.5.0.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 828056 Jun 28  2010 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.5.0.7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     19 Jul 23 08:54 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.13
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 989840 Jun  1 07:39 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
```

So I modified `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as was suggested in another SO post:

```
PROMPT ] export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Tried running again and got another error:

```
PROMPT ] oldpy ./myScript.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myScript.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/oldinstall/Python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from pandas.io.api import *
  File "/oldinstall/Python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/api.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas.io.packers import read_msgpack, to_msgpack
  File "/oldinstall/Python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/packers.py", line 63, in <module>
    from pandas.msgpack import Unpacker as _Unpacker, Packer as _Packer
ImportError: libstdc++.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

How can I get rid of this error and, ultimately, be able to run the old python version with `pandas`? Whatever I do to achieve this, however, I don't want to mess up the environment for the current version of python I am using (which, in case this is relevant, was installed into a local subdirectory of my home dir using `miniconda`)

Answer (score 0):

The version of python you're trying to use wasn't compiled for 64 bit, so it isn't linked against a 64 bit `libstdc++`.

The proper way to run the older version of python would be doing an install on the machine.  I'm not sure how Redhat handles multiple package versions, but I'd be surprised if it didn't support it (most distributions do).

Other than that, you would need to find a host that the older version is installed on.